# NetSuite Web Service Sales Order Error - Invalid orderstatus reference key B

Tags: php, netsuite

I've recently run into the following error when connecting to a new NetSuite instance and trying to create a SalesOrder:

```
<platformCore:statusDetail type="ERROR">
<platformCore:code>INVALID_KEY_OR_REF</platformCore:code>
<platformCore:message>Invalid orderstatus reference key B.</platformCore:message>
```

The reason I'm having trouble with this error is because:

1. I'm not sending `B` as the orderstatus, I'm sending `_pendingFulfillment`
2. This same call format works against a different NetSuite account

Does anyone have any clue what could be causing this error? Something on my end, or some configuration within the NetSuite account?

I'm using NetSuite's PHP library, but the raw XML posted looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2018_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2018_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformCommon="urn:common_2018_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_2018_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranSales="urn:sales_2018_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranPurch="urn:purchases_2018_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:actSched="urn:scheduling_2018_2.activities.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:setupCustom="urn:customization_2018_2.setup.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listAcct="urn:accounting_2018_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranBank="urn:bank_2018_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranCust="urn:customers_2018_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranEmp="urn:employees_2018_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranInvt="urn:inventory_2018_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listSupport="urn:support_2018_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:tranGeneral="urn:general_2018_2.transactions.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:commGeneral="urn:communication_2018_2.general.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listMkt="urn:marketing_2018_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listWebsite="urn:website_2018_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:fileCabinet="urn:filecabinet_2018_2.documents.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:listEmp="urn:employees_2018_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com">
<env:Header>
<platformMsgs:tokenPassport>
<platformCore:account>3537721</platformCore:account>
<platformCore:consumerKey>***REMOVED***</platformCore:consumerKey>
<platformCore:token>***REMOVED***</platformCore:token>
<platformCore:nonce>rWHjYyEwmMG7g9z4MkhC</platformCore:nonce>
<platformCore:timestamp>1595380696</platformCore:timestamp>
<platformCore:signature algorithm="HMAC-SHA256">***REMOVED***</platformCore:signature>
</platformMsgs:tokenPassport>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<platformMsgs:add>
<platformMsgs:record xsi:type="tranSales:SalesOrder">
<tranSales:orderStatus>_pendingFulfillment</tranSales:orderStatus>
<tranSales:otherRefNum/>
<tranSales:toBePrinted>false</tranSales:toBePrinted>
<tranSales:toBeEmailed>false</tranSales:toBeEmailed>
<tranSales:toBeFaxed>false</tranSales:toBeFaxed>
<tranSales:email>***REMOVED***</tranSales:email>
<tranSales:itemList>
<tranSales:item>
<tranSales:item internalId="67004" type="inventoryItem"/>
<tranSales:quantity>1</tranSales:quantity>
</tranSales:item>
</tranSales:itemList>
<tranSales:customForm internalId="100"/>
<tranSales:tranDate>2020-07-20T05:18:20+00:00</tranSales:tranDate>
<tranSales:salesEffectiveDate>2020-07-20T05:18:20+00:00</tranSales:salesEffectiveDate>
<tranSales:shipDate>2020-07-20T05:18:20+00:00</tranSales:shipDate>
<tranSales:entity internalId="644" type="customer"/>
<tranSales:currency internalId="1" type="currency"/>
<tranSales:terms internalId="2" type="term"/>
<tranSales:subsidiary internalId="1" type="subsidiary"/>
<tranSales:location internalId="10" type="location"/>
<tranSales:customFieldList>
<platformCore:customField xsi:type="platformCore:SelectCustomFieldRef" internalId="560" scriptId="custbody_bwt_availmons_so">
<platformCore:value internalId="11" typeId="175"/>
</platformCore:customField>
<platformCore:customField xsi:type="platformCore:StringCustomFieldRef" internalId="725" scriptId="custbody17">
<platformCore:value>185216_Nov</platformCore:value>
</platformCore:customField>
<platformCore:customField xsi:type="platformCore:MultiSelectCustomFieldRef" internalId="281" scriptId="custbody10">
<platformCore:value>yes</platformCore:value>
</platformCore:customField>
<platformCore:customField xsi:type="platformCore:DateCustomFieldRef" internalId="91" scriptId="custbody_del_due_date">
<platformCore:value>2020-07-20T05:18:20+00:00</platformCore:value>
</platformCore:customField>
<platformCore:customField xsi:type="platformCore:StringCustomFieldRef" internalId="24" scriptId="custbody5">
<platformCore:value/>
</platformCore:customField>
</tranSales:customFieldList>
</platformMsgs:record>
</platformMsgs:add>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: It appears this field may sometimes (always?) be read-only. The NetSuite Schema Browser not only doesn't mention that, but lists it as required and explicitly says in the records browser that you can edit the field. I have no clue why it returns this random error message nor why on some accounts it doesn't complain at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this issue on accounts where the default Sales Order status is Pending Fulfillment -- essentially you can't set it to what it already is. I'd guess it's because the order status is part of a state machine and there is no valid transition from Pending Fulfillment to Pending Fulfillment.

The default status is set up in your account under Accounting Preferences or you can get this with a script call referencing the DEFSALESORDSTATUS preference. I don't believe the preferences are exposed to SuiteTalk.

FWIW 'B' is the internal value of the Pending Fulfillment orderstatus. and 'SalesOrd:B' is the internal value that would be used on a scripted search for orders in Pending Fulfillment status.

Comment: For my case leaving it as the default status in NetSuite works. I have tested sending through the order and leaving off this field entirely and it works fine. Thanks for the background here which helps me understand why that was happening.